# Density of a level set of a discontinuous element in $\operatorname{L}(V,W)$.

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I really need a  hint or an idea to start proving this proposition:

Let $V$ and $W$ be two normed spaces with $V':=\operatorname{L}(V,W)=\{f:V\to W\}$.

Prove for $V$ on the field of real numbers, that every level set of any discontinuous element in $V'$ is dense in $V$.

Comment: Do you mean that you consider $V'$ specifically in the case where $W=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I don't understand how a linear transformation could be dscontinuous, please make it clear

Comment: Sorry I missed it while I was editing. $f$ is a generic transformation from a normed space $V$ to a normed space $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the statement can't be true for general $W$ if we accept the axiom of choice.

Indeed, note that if $\tilde{V}\subseteq V$ is any proper subspace, then there exists a linear map $f:V\to V$ such that $\textrm{ker} f=\tilde{V}$. This is a standard application of Zorn's Lemma by choosing $\{v_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ to be some algebraic basis of $V$ such that there is some subset $B\subseteq A$ such that $\{v_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in B}$ is a basis of $\tilde{V}$. Then, you can simply define $$
f(v_{\alpha})=\begin{cases} 0 & \alpha\in B \\ v_{\alpha} & else\end{cases}
$$
This map is easily seen to be linear and satisfy the desired properties. Note that such an $f$ is automatically discontinuous if $\bar{V}$ is not closed (which, of course, can only happen in infinite dimension).

In particular, we get a discontinuous, injective linear map $h:V\to V^2$ given by $g(v)=(f(v),v)$. Hence, every level set is at most a singleton and, in particular, no level set is dense.

However, the statement *is* true for $W=\mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, note that a discontinuous, linear $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$ is not the $0$-map and hence, must be surjective. Furthermore, note that for all $\varepsilon>0$, the restriction of $f$ to $B(0,\varepsilon)$ must also be surjective. This follows since for some $\delta>0$ and every $n$, there exists $y_n\in B(0,2^{-n}\varepsilon)$ such that $|f(y_n)|\geq \delta$ (this is just rephrasing discontinuity at $0$). This, of course gives, by linearity, that $2^ny_n,-2^ny_n\in B(0,\varepsilon)$ and $|f(\pm2^n y_n)|\geq 2^n\delta$. Since $f(2^ny_n)=-f(-2^ny_n)$, the intermediate value theorem tells us that the image of $B(0,\varepsilon)$ contains $[-2^n\delta,2^n\delta]$ for every $n$. Thus, $f$ restricted to $B(0,\varepsilon)$ is surjective.

This gives us that for $x\in V$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $y\in B(0,\varepsilon)$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. In particular, $x-y\in B(x,\varepsilon)$ and $f(x-y)=0$. This establishes that $\textrm{ker}(f)$ is dense in $V$. However, that means that $x+\textrm{ker}f$ is dense in $V$ for every $x$. Since $x+\textrm{ker}f=\{y|\; f(y)=f(x)\},$ and $f$ is surjective, we get the desired.

Comment: One may note, of course, that we aren't using the fact that $V$ is normed at all. The above is equally valid for general topological space (in the second part, simply replace balls with general neighbourhoods around $0$).